# Why is my flask app not writing to log file? (hosted through apache2 on ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, logging, apache2

My webapp uses Python/Flask and is hosted through Apache2 on an Ubuntu server.

I would like to write to a logfile using Python's logging module. My development server is on Windows and the logging works as expected there, but I can't get it working on the Ubuntu testing server.

Here is how I set it up:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
log_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("var", "www", "webApp", "webApp", "logfile.log"))
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(log_location),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)])
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/var/www/webApp/webApp/web-app-build/build/')
logging.info("Testing the logger...")
```

With this I would expect this log to write to the logfile on `/var/www/webApp/webApp/logfile.log`, but even though the file is created, when I vim it, it is empty.

What can I change to
make it work?

- I know I can access the log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but I'd
  like to instead access it at the above location.
- As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250396/flask-application-logfile-is-not-written-under-apache-deployment), I have ensured to set up the logger before setting
  up the app. I also tried setting up the logger in the `__init__.py` (code below), but results seem to stay the same.
- I have ensured that www-data has full permissions for the directory
  where the logfile is to be written.

Something interesting that I am seeing is this:
When I reload apache2 to reboot the app, the logfile is not yet created. Then when I do something on the app that would cause logging to happen, the logfile is created. However, it is empty. If I then delete the logfile and do some more things in the application that would normally cause logging the logfile is not recreated.

```
from rest.server import app
import os
import logging
import sys

log_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("var", "www", "webApp", "webApp", "logfile.log"))
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(log_location),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)])
logging.info("Testing the logger...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default flask uses the Python's `logging` package to write its logs.You must connect your logging config the **Flask logger object**, which is `app.logger`:

```
from rest.server import app
import os
import logging
from logging import FileHandler
import sys

log_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("var", "www", "webApp", "webApp", "logfile.log"))
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s'
file_handler = FileHandler(log_location)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app.logger.info("Testing the logger...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```